Modeling the world and low entropy
Is it correct to think that modeling the world is only computationally feasible because of our universe's current relatively low entropy state? I thought this was obvious when I was learning information science but I never posed it to a physicist.
By world I mean some aspect of the world or some subset of its particles. By modeling, I mean predicting the evolution of some part of the world to some precision.
Example: If Jupiter was frozen and had no movement, it would be easy to model its weather system. If you add energy, say increase the orbit of the planet around the sun, you wouldn't increase the difficulty in modeling the weather of Jupiter. However, If you heated the planet and the entropy on the surface increased, it would be more difficult to model the weather.
What really bothers me is why even with higher entropy on the surface of Jupiter it is still relatively easy to model the orbit of Jupiter around the sun. Why didn't that become more difficult? Maybe it did but I don't see how.

What do you mean by "modeling of the world is computationally feasible"? We can't predict weather few days into future.

One could argue that modeling anything might be computationally simpler if its entropy is either minimal or maximized; I wouldn’t expect a universal monotonic change in computation difficulty. Clarification and context is needed on the model, the type of computation, “the world,” etc.

@JánLalinský What makes modeling the weather so difficult?

@Joemoor94 the fact there is too many variables, and we don't have appropriate hardware to calculate evolution equations with them. Tim Palmer has a lecture on youtube where he says the smallest pixel in numerical models of climate is something like a 100x100km square. With more detail for what goes on inside, it starts to be too many calculations to get a result in acceptable time.

@JánLalinský If we lowered the entropy in the weather systems seems like we could calculate an adequate model in an acceptable amount of time

@Chemomechanics I'm not claiming there would be a monotonic function in computation because you can always change the state variable (position/momentum -> temperature) but it seems like there is a general principle here

If higher entropy can be considered to be a greater lack of information about individual particle movement, can we replace the comparison by a comparison of a moving object at near 0 K and a motionless object that’s warmer, with the same energy? It’s not clear what the introduction of Jupiter and weather provides.

"why even with higher entropy on the surface of Jupiter it is still relatively easy to model the orbit of Jupiter around the sun"? Because when we model the orbit of a planet, we abstract away the planet structure, and only consider its mass. The entropy of any system in the planet itself is irrelevant. Why don't we consider international trading, animal migrations or volcanic activity on Earth when modelling the moon orbit? Because we would see that none of that would make the end result noticeably different. Modelling is all about deciding what is negligible and what is not.


Is it correct to think that modeling the world is only computationally feasible because of our universe's current relatively low entropy state?

I think your underlying assumption - that it is feasible to computational model or simulate large parts of our world - is incorrect. We model those parts of our world that can be feasibly modelled, or simplified into a feasible model without losing significant features. There are large parts of our world (weather, financial markets, turbulence in fluids, brains, genetics, most organic chemistry, evolution of galaxies etc. etc.) for which we have no feasible computational model.

Some components of our world can be modeled in that they can be accurately predicted. I'm not sure where you're getting "large parts of our world" from. The point I'm getting at is that it seems entropy increasing makes it hard to make predictions.

@Joemoor94 "entropy increasing makes it hard to make predictions" - on the contrary. When entropy is maximised in an isolated system it is in equilibrium, so macroscopic prediction is easy since nothing changes i.e. the system's macrostate is stationary.

@gandolf61 but isn't this dependent on the particular state variable you are trying to predict? Like total energy of the universe is conserved across time so I can always predict this. But the exact position of any particle in a set requires more storage compacity(larger transformation computation) as the entropy rises. Lattice structures reduce the need for computation/information storage.
